# Play video from remote URL (e.g. https://somevideolink) in apple WatchKit app using swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am playing a video in WatchKit app that is present in my project with file name as someMovie.mov.
I used two ways which are available by default in watch OS and  also recommended by Apple such as

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "someMovie", withExtension: "mov")

1. self.presentMediaPlayerController(with: url, options: options, completion: { (didPlayToEnd, endTime, error) in
   print(didPlayToEnd)
   })
2. let videoPlayer = WKInterfaceMovie();
        videoPlayer.setMovie(url: url)

But when I pass remote URL which is present at https protocol (e.g.  https://somevideolink) to the Video player then the presented video player interface opens and shows loading for some time and quits automatically.

After searching more online i got some clue that I had to use AppGroup and save the streaming video offline as .mov or .mp4 extension in Library folder of app in device and show on UI after the video has been completely downloaded.

is there any other solution to play any remote video in watchKit app ?